# Kundera: error in the persistence configuration cassandra+eclipse+kundera

Tags: cassandra, persistence, kundera

I have a problem with the persistence in my cassandra+kundera+eclipse project. The error that's reported is this:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence). log4j:WARN Please initialize
>   the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException:
>   com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not
>   find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath   at
>   com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:100)
>     at
>   com.impetus.kundera.configure.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:65)
>     at
>   com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:109)
>     at
>   com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:81)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at controlador.Conetor.main(Conetor.java:17) Caused by:
>   com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not
>   find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath   at
>   com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.findPersistenceMetadatas(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:132)
>     at
>   com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:83)
>     ... 6 more

And the persistence source is this:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="cassandra_pu">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>     
        <properties>            
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="kundera.port" value="9160"/>
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="KunderaExamples"/>
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class"
                value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />

        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[POM XML WITH DE JAR KUNDERA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyK4H.png)

Comment: Be careful to indent all your code snippets by four spaces. Otherwise they will no be displayed properly (or at all). And when you are pasting in error messages and stack traces and such, you want to format them with a `>` before each line. The StackOverflow built-in editor has buttons for doing those things; you just highlight your code snippet or error message, and press the button, and it does the rest for you.

Comment: @DanielFerreira what is the location of your `persistence.xml`? It should be in the classpath (preferably src/main/resources) in `META-INF` folder. Eg: `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: @DanielFerreira Also.. I suggest you to use the latest version of Kundera i.e [`Kundera 3.1`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.impetus.kundera.client/kundera-cassandra/3.1)

Comment: thanks you, i have the persistence.xml in this location:  target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: @karthikmanchala it's the Maven Webapp project

Comment: @DanielFerreira can you make the folder `web-resources` as a source folder and try? (In eclipse you can just right click `web-resources` > `Build Path` > `Use as Source Folder`)

Comment: thank, i think that i solver the problem. i used java resource/src/main/java/META-INF/persistence-xml. the maven project web run  and run many lines but in the finish there is a error :_( the erros is this.

Comment: first the project try run the program, try connect with the localhost and try connect with my keyspace > (RIRI) [DEBUG] [main] org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.LeastLoadedNodeSelectionStrategy  - Node 'localhost' has 0 active connections, 0 borrowed connections and 0 corrupted connections
2015-10-20 12:17:23,621 [DEBUG] [main] org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool  - Attempting to borrow free connection for node 'localhost'
2015-10-20 12:17:23,621 [DEBUG] [main] org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool  - Made new connection 'Connection[RIRI][localhost:9160][2055192420]'

Comment: after the connect with the keyspace fail 2015-10-20 12:17:23,621 [DEBUG] [main] org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Connection  - set keyspace  'RIRI'
2015-10-20 12:17:23,621 [WARN ] [main] org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Connection  - Failed to set keyspace on client for node localhost.  Cause is InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace 'RIRI' does not exist)

Comment: @DanielFerreira You have `KunderaExamples` as your keyspace in `persistence.xml` and I think `RIRI` in your entity. Please use same keyspace name at both locations. Also, make sure that keyspace exists in Cassandra. If not, you can add `<property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="create" />` line in your `persistence.xml` for auto-schema creation.

Answer (score 1):

Please put your persistence.xml in below path. It should resolve this error.  `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`